# Fix chat.SE and chat.SO main page minimum width

Tags: script, userstyle

Use this to get rid of the annoying horizontal scrollbar on [chat.SE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) and [chat.SO](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) main pages. The rest of the design is already adaptive and just works.

```
@-moz-document domain("chat.stackexchange.com"), domain("chat.stackoverflow.com") {
.topbar .topbar-wrapper {
    width:unset !important;
    max-width: 1060px;
    min-width: 560px; }
body.outside #container {
    width:unset !important;
    max-width: 950px;
    min-width: 250px; }
.footerwrap {width:unset !important;}
.roomcard {margin: 0px 2px 10px 2px}
}
```